# How can I use the index array in tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

If given a matrix `a` with shape `(5,3)` and index array `b` with shape `(5,)`, we can easily get the corresponding vector `c` through,

`c = a[np.arange(5), b]`

However, I cannot do the same thing with tensorflow,

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(5, 3))
b = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [5,])
# this line throws error
c = a[tf.range(5), b]
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py",
>   line 513, in _SliceHelper
>       name=name)
>
> File
>   "~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py",
>   line 671, in strided_slice
>       shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask)   File "~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py",
>   line 3688, in strided_slice
>       shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask, name=name)   File "~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py",
>   line 763, in apply_op
>       op_def=op_def)   File "~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 2397, in create_op
>       set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)   File "~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1757, in set_shapes_for_outputs
>       shapes = shape_func(op)   File "~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1707, in call_with_requiring
>       return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)   File "~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py",
>   line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn
>       debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)   File "~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py",
>   line 675, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
>       raise ValueError(err.message) ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice_14' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input
>   shapes: [5,3], [2,5], [2,5], [2].

My question is, if I cannot produce the expected result in tensorflow as in numpy using the above mentioned method, what should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This feature is not currently implemented in TensorFlow. GitHub [issue #4638](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4638) is tracking the implementation of NumPy-style "advanced" indexing. However, you can use the [`tf.gather_nd()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) operator to implement your program:

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(5, 3))
b = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (5,))

row_indices = tf.range(5)

# `indices` is a 5 x 2 matrix of coordinates into `a`.
indices = tf.transpose([row_indices, b])

c = tf.gather_nd(a, indices)
```