# Indexing tensor in tensorflow using a tensor of integers

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

My question is similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622815/how-can-i-use-the-index-array-in-tensorflow) but not exactly the same. I have two tensors

```
mu: (shape=(1000,1), dtype=np.float32)
p : (shape=(100,30), dtype=np.int64)
```

What I want is to create a new tensor

```
x : (shape=(100,30), dtype=np.float32)
```

such that

```
x[i,j] = mu[p[i,j]]
```

This can be done in numpy using advanced indexing

```
x = mu[p]
```

I have tried using the `tf.gather_nd(mu, p)` command but in my case I receive the following error

```
*** ValueError: indices.shape[-1] must be <= params.rank, but saw indices shape: [100,30] and params shape: [1000] for 'GatherNd_2' (op: 'GatherNd') with input shapes: [1000], [100,30].
```

It therefore seems in order to use this, I have to build a new tensor of coordinates. Is there a more simple way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working solution:

```
tf.reshape(tf.gather(mu[:,0], tf.reshape(p, (-1,))), p.shape)
```

Basically it

1. flattens the index array to 1d, `tf.reshape(p, (-1,))`;
2. gather the elements from `mu[:,0]` (first column of `mu`);
3. and then reshape it to `p`'s shape.

---

*Minimal Example*:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.InteractiveSession()

mu = tf.reshape(tf.multiply(tf.cast(tf.range(10), tf.float32), 0.1), (10, 1))
mu.eval()
#array([[ 0.        ],
#       [ 0.1       ],
#       [ 0.2       ],
#       [ 0.30000001],
#       [ 0.40000001],
#       [ 0.5       ],
#       [ 0.60000002],
#       [ 0.69999999],
#       [ 0.80000001],
#       [ 0.90000004]], dtype=float32)

p = tf.constant([[1,3],[2,4],[3,1]], dtype=tf.int64)

tf.reshape(tf.gather(mu[:,0], tf.reshape(p, (-1,))), p.shape).eval()

#array([[ 0.1       ,  0.30000001],
#       [ 0.2       ,  0.40000001],
#       [ 0.30000001,  0.1       ]], dtype=float32)
```

---

Another two options using `gather_nd` without reshaping:

```
tf.gather_nd(mu[:,0], tf.expand_dims(p, axis=-1)).eval()

#array([[ 0.1       ,  0.30000001],
#       [ 0.2       ,  0.40000001],
#       [ 0.30000001,  0.1       ]], dtype=float32)

tf.gather_nd(mu, tf.stack((p, tf.zeros_like(p)), axis=-1)).eval()

#array([[ 0.1       ,  0.30000001],
#       [ 0.2       ,  0.40000001],
#       [ 0.30000001,  0.1       ]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn):

```
 x= tf.map_fn(lambda u: tf.gather(tf.squeeze(mu),u),p,dtype=mu.dtype)
```

`map_fn` acts as a loop that runs over the first dimensions of `p`, and for each such slice it applies `tf.gather`.